# Can I add a proprietary wireless driver to a liveUSB stick?

Tags: wireless, drivers, live-usb

I'm looking to try out Natty with a liveUSB stick, but I've and internet access problem. I've only wireless internet access (Mifi dongle) and my laptop has a broadcom wireless adapter (BC4312) which needs a proprietary driver.

I was wondering if there was any way of adding the wifi drivers to liveUSB stick after I've created it using the startup disk creator in my maverick install?

Comment: AFAIK, reading the methods to make a live disk, you cant add the proprietary drivers.

Comment: Well if you have a persistent key it could work, though I suspect you would need to plug into ethernet, get it all working, then install the driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Answer (score 1):

The broadcom STA driver that supports your device is already on the installation media.  Tell it to install 3rd party software during install and it will activate it before partitioner comes up.  connect to your wifi, continue install.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an advanced user but been using Ubuntu since 2005

You can actually do and at the same time you cant,

## Scenario 1 - Getting live just ONCE

When you get Live through your usb stick, just get a wired cable, and install the wireless drivers. Once you are done with it, surf internet using your wireless NIC card. Okay i know that sounds lame.

## Scenario 2 - Getting live again and again

Get your ubuntu iso image burned on a cd or dvd (whatever suits you). Get live, and install ubuntu on the usb disk.

Now whenever you plug the usb, you ll find that ubuntu is actually installed over it (saving + dynamic storage). Get a wired connection for a while and install the drivers once. And enjoy using wireless every time you boot from usb.

Note: I dont know, may be there are ways to tweak the image. However i consider scenario2 the most safer one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ubuntu page for [Natty Alpha 2](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/alpha2) persistance does not work for the live usb and is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/683260) so you will not be able to save any changes or updates to the usb key