# Fix Ubuntu 14.04 installation with Live USB drive

Tags: wireless, drivers, live-usb, flash

Recently when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I lost my ability to use WiFi. I don't have hard line access.

Fortunately I kept an old usb stick around with Ubuntu 10.10 which CAN access the internet through WiFi. The problem is I don't have access to a router now to get the drivers.

The last time I installed Ubuntu, I found that the wireless drivers  I need are proprietary, and aren't included by default. Without access to the router, I can't download them because I only get internet through wireless.

Essentially, I need internet to fix the internet.

The installation of Ubuntu 10.10 on the USB still has the wireless drivers on it, because I made the image persistent.

Is there some way I could transfer the wireless drivers from the USB to the Ubuntu 14.04 installation on the hard drive?

Comment: If you "upgraded" instead of reinstalling, you might still have the drivers around as older kernel modules.  Can you boot with an older kernel?  If so, just copy the necessary modules from /lib/modules/<old> to /lib/modules/<new>

Comment: No sorry it's a fresh install. I actually upgraded to try and fix a different problem which persisted through the upgrade so I formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! This question: [Can I add a proprietary wireless driver to a liveUSB stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25996/can-i-add-a-proprietary-wireless-driver-to-a-liveusb-stick?rq=1) basically answers it. The user daffydack said that the driver IS ACTUALLY ON THE INSTALLATION MEDIUM. So I reinstalled a few times and with a few different versions and still couldn't get wireless... but the last time I interrupted an installation causing it to go to the live cd / test phase. Then I looked at the additional drivers thing and still couldn't get them. Then I closed it and opened it. Then like a few minutes later it just popped up. So I installed the drivers and attempted to install the os assuming the changes to the live environment would carry over. Then it wouldn't install the os. Then I cancelled that and did some googling. Then in one last ditch effort tried the install again. And here I am in a fresh new install. Btw if someone reads this please tell me, is it always such a pain in the butt trying to install ubuntu or am I just cursed? I always have problems. You would think with the amount of development that has gone into other areas of this project that the foundations (booting installing etc) would be pretty solid... :s